# Update one collection based on another collection value

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I am looking at the best way of updating one collection based on another collection.

First of the system matches a user as being fully available then gets availability from the system to update the collection. The first collection needs to be updated with values from the second collection. This works but is slow.

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;

// setup as fully available
var listAvailabilityNotBooked = new List<Availability>();

for (int i = -2; i < 10; i++)
{
    listAvailabilityNotBooked.Add(new Availability
    {
        Month = currentDate.AddMonths(i).Month,
        Year = currentDate.AddMonths(i).Year,
        Percentage = 0
    });
}

// match booked up from system
var availability = _availabilityRepository.GetAll();
foreach (Availability notBooked in listAvailabilityNotBooked)
{
    // not booked becomes booked if match in system
    notBooked.Percentage =
        availability.Where(i => i.Month == notBooked.Month && i.Year == notBooked.Year)
            .Select(i => i.Percentage).FirstOrDefault();
}

var availabilityDetail = new AvailabilityDetail
{
    Availability = listAvailabilityNotBooked,
    EmailEnquiryForm = new EmailEnquiryForm()
};
```

I refactored to:

- it needs to lookup on both month and year
- still slow on multiple data add month and where clause

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;

// match booked up from system
IQueryable<Availability> availability = _availabilityRepository.GetAll();

// setup as fully available
List<Availability> availabilityBooked = new List<Availability>();

for (int i = -2; i < 10; i++)
{
    var month = currentDate.AddMonths(i).Month;
    var year = currentDate.AddMonths(i).Year;

    availabilityBooked.Add(new Availability
    {
        Month = month,
        Year = year,
        Percentage = availability.Where(a => a.Month == month && a.Year == year)
          .Select(a => a.Percentage).FirstOrDefault()
    });
}
```

Comment: Word of advice, it's good practice to use the actual type name rather than "var" (e.g. "var listAvailabilityNotBooked = new List<Availability>();" should be "List<Availability> listAvailabilityNotBooked = new List<Availability>();". Just in case you end up with a lot of variables with different types but similar names ^_^

Comment: i need to show two months prior current date and in the future availabity -if not in the system need to use default percentage of 0%

Comment: @Rariolu: Who said it's a good practice? In fact many people consider `var` to be a good practice and much more readable. In reality it's just a matter of personal preference and coding style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [`Lookup<Tkey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the percentage for every month quickly:

```
var monthPercentageLookup = _availabilityRepository.GetAll()
    .ToLookup(x => new{ x.Year, x.Month }, x => x.Percentage);
foreach (Availability notBooked in listAvailabilityNotBooked)
{
    var month = new { notBooked.Year, notBooked.Month };
    notBooked.Percentage = monthPercentageLookup[month].FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: hi i need to lookup against month and year for percentage

Comment: @Matt: and that's what i've done, i've used an anonymous type which contains the year and the month.